# Can I pass options to a babel preset using the Browserify CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, browserify

I am able to use the browserify CLI to compile some React app JavaScript as follows:

```
browserify \
 --transform [ babelify --presets [ @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react ] \
 -o output.js input.js
```

However, I want to pass an option to the "@babel/preset-env" preset. I thought I would be to do this by simply nesting more brackets, like:

```
browserify \
 --transform [ babelify --presets [ \
  [ @babel/preset-env --useBuiltins usage ] \
  @babel/preset-react \
 ] \
 -o output.js input.js
```

But then I start getting a weird error from Babel that seems to indicate that it is not getting passed the option as I expect:

> ReferenceError: [BABEL] input.js: Unknown option: ._. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options. while parsing file: input.js

How do I pass the equivalent of

```
transform: [
  ['babelify', {
    presets: [
      ['@babel/preset-env', {useBuiltIns:'usage'}],
      '@babel/preset-react'
    ]
  }]
```

via the browserify command line interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babelify does not support passing preset or plugin options via the CLI. Usually, the `-p [ @babel/preset-env --no-modules ]` syntax would be used for that, but babelify uses it for passing arrays instead. Instead, you have to use a `.babelrc`.